# HasData data seeding doesn't work properly EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a `AppSetting` Entity. I removed `AppSettings` table data from `SQL Server database` by manually. EF core's HasData propery data seeding can't seed the data after this deletion.

My guess is about maybe Private Key Field.But I am not sure. So I gave new Ids.

First ids were `1,2,3`. But when they have been like this EF Core didnt seed the data. I have changed as `3,4,5`.Has data have been work only datas which were `4,5` ids. But the entity which have id with `3` value didnt seed.

Sos here is my Entity.

```
public class AppSetting:EntityBase
{
    public string SettingName { get; set; }
    public string SettingSlug { get; set; }

    public string SettingDesc { get; set; }

    public int? DefinitionId { get; set; }

    public string SettingValue { get; set; }
    public virtual Definition Definition { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Here is `HasData` Seeding in `ApplicationDbContext`

```
       builder.Entity<AppSetting>().HasData(
            new AppSetting { 
                Id = 3, 
                SettingName = "Üyelik Modeli", 
                SettingSlug = "uyelik_modeli", 
                SettingValue = null,
                SettingDesc = "Lojistik firmalar için ÜYELİK MODELİ tanım bilgilerini içerir.",
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, 
                UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                DefinitionId = null,
                Active = false 
            },
            new AppSetting { 
                Id = 4, 
                SettingName = "Sektör", 
                SettingSlug = "sektor", 
                SettingValue = null,
                SettingDesc = "Lojistik firmalar için SEKTÖR tanım bilgilerini içerir.",
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, 
                UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                DefinitionId = null,
                Active = false 
            },
            new AppSetting { 
                Id = 5, 
                SettingName = "Görev", 
                SettingSlug = "gorev", 
                SettingValue = null,
                SettingDesc = "Kullanıcılar için GÖREV tanım bilgilerini içerir.",
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, 
                UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                DefinitionId = null,
                Active = false 
            }
        );
```

How can I fix this seeding issue.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using an array instead of passing each object one by one?

Comment: is there any difference with passing array?

Comment: don't you need a migration for this? how does it look like?